# Error building boofcv calibration app with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, boofcv

I've followed build instructions from here:

https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Tutorial_Camera_Calibration

and get this strange error message:

```
C:\boofcv\applications>gradle applicationsJar
Skipping integration/android because ANDROID_HOME has not been set!  See integration/android/readme.txt
Skipping integration/boofcv-openkinect because boofcv-openkinect/libfreenect is missing! See integration/openkinect/readme.txt
Parallel execution is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':applications:applicationsJar' property 'rootSpec$1$1$2$1' during up-to-date check.
> A Jar can only accept a file or directory that exists: C:\boofcv\applications\build\osgi-classes

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
38 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 28 up-to-date
```

my boofcv version is 0.27.

Comment: https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/issues/88

Comment: Probably won't fix it but you should use ./gradlew instead of gradle